# Ubuntu and Postfix Configuration Issues

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I recently installed postfix on Ubuntu Natty. I'm having a problem with the configuration.

Firstly here is my postfix configuration file:

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

mydomain = $myorigin
myhostname = mail.nairanode.com

alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
# this specifies where the virtual mailbox folders will be located
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
# this specifies where the virtual mailbox folders will be located
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
# this is for the mailbox location for each user
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf
# and this is for aliases
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf
# and this is for domain lookups
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf
# this is how to connect to the domains (all virtual, but the option is there)
# not used yet
# transport_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_transport.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

mydestination = $myorigin, $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
#mynetworks_style = host

# ADDITIONAL
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12

# Requirements for the HELO statement
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
# Requirements for the sender details
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_$
# Requirements for the connecting server
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.n$
# Requirement for the recipient address
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_do$

# require proper helo at connections
smtpd_helo_required = yes
# waste spammers time before rejecting them
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
```

Here is also my /etc/postfix/aliases:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
```

Here is also my /etc/mailname:

```
nairanode.com
```

I've also updated my hostname to nairanode.com

However, when I run `postalias /etc/postfix/aliases` I get the following :

```
postalias: warning: valid_hostname: invalid character 47(decimal): /etc/mailname
postalias: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter mydomain: bad parameter value: /etc/mailname
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?! I noticed that when I replace `myorigin = /etc/mailname` with `myorigin = nairanode.com` in my postfix config, I don't see any errors anymore after calling postalias. Is this a bug or something?!

Comment: You may have encoding problem or invisible characters in the file `/etc/mailname`. Try to see its contents using `cat -A /etc/mailname`. You can also try to remove the file and recreate it again.

Comment: @Khaled Here's what I get when I use the cat operation you listed `nairanode.com$`. Is that a problem?

Comment: No, it should be fine. Did you try to remove/recreate the file?

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to specify

```
mydomain = $myorigin
```

You can do either remove the setting completely or specify a valid entry like mail.nairanode.com. But you are not allowed to use variables like $myorigin!

If you want it to be "dynamic" configurable by an external file, then you have to remove `mydomain` *and* `myhostname` completely. In this case the domain will be extracted from the hostname and the hostname will be extracted from `/etc/hosts` (better: by the gethostname() system call)

---

See the first three lines of your `main.cf` why you now experience a Debian-Postfix "bug". But Debian/Ubuntu intentionally hack Postfix to allow this stupid things. But they didn't think about the consequences of using this hack via Postfix $variables. Complain at Debian, not Postfix!

Comment: If you want to be "dynamic", it's better to just use one of the  "virtual mail howto's" in the first place (postfix/dovecot + database) (my preference). See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixVirtualMailBoxClamSmtpHowto as one example.